# How do I change Chrome's media notification background colors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, colors, notifications, media

I want to know how to change media notification colors in Google Chrome.

[Crunchyroll, Vimeo and Dailymotion media notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O631y.png)

Crunchyroll, Vimeo and Dailymotion have their unique media notifications. How can I change the background color of a media notification in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default color is like you said, the main favicon color. But you can customize the media notification with artwork, then is that main artwork color the background color.

```
navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({title: 'white', artwork: [
    { src: BASE_URL + 'big-buck-bunny/artwork-512.png', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
  ]})
```

[image]

Check out the webdev guide for the implementation [link](https://web.dev/media-session/)

And the [example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/audio.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found the solution. It seems the color is based on the favicon color.